# File permissions for child process

Tags: c, struct

C Programming Question

> Im trying to a have a parent process print a child process for every
>   file passed through as argument or if no arguments are passed then grab every file in the current directory. For all the files print permissions. I believe the problem is the location of my struct stat buf; (currently global). Currently my output prints out the file name and directory but not the permission. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void permission();
typedef int bool;
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

struct stat buf;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
bool commandline = FALSE; //determine if 0 args passed
if (argc < 2){commandline=TRUE;}
struct passwd *passwd;
passwd = getpwuid(getuid());
char *file, *dir;
uid_t uid;  //user id
gid_t gid;  //group
uid = getuid();
gid = getgid();
DIR *d;
struct dirent *directory;
d = opendir(".");
struct stat buf;

int i,pid=1;
for (i = 1; (i < argc && pid) || (commandline==TRUE) ; i++) {
    if (!(pid = fork())) {
        if (argc > 1) {
            dir = passwd->pw_dir;
            file = malloc(sizeof(dir) + 1 + sizeof(argv[i]));
            strcat(file, dir);
            strcat(file, "/");
            strcat(file, argv[i]);
            printf("File: %s\nDirectory: %s\n", argv[i], file);
            permission();
        } else {
            if (d) {
                while ((directory = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
                    dir = passwd->pw_dir;
                    printf("File: %s\n",directory->d_name);
                    printf("Directory: %s/%s\n",dir, directory->d_name);
                    permission();
                }
            }
        }
    } /* IF CHILD */
    commandline=FALSE;
} /* FOR LOOP */
while (wait(NULL) > 0);

} /* !Main */

/* PRINT FILE PERMISSIONS*/
void permission() {
int fileMode;

fileMode = buf.st_mode;
if (fileMode & S_IRUSR) {
    printf("You have Owner permissions:");
    if (fileMode & S_IREAD) { printf(" Read "); }
    if (fileMode & S_IWRITE) { printf("Write "); }
    if (fileMode & S_IEXEC) { printf("Execute"); }
    printf("\n\n");
} else if (fileMode & S_IRGRP) {
    printf("You have Group permissions:\n");
    if (fileMode & S_IREAD) { printf(" Read "); }
    if (fileMode & S_IWRITE) { printf("Write "); }
    if (fileMode & S_IEXEC) { printf("Execute"); }
    printf("\n\n");
} else if (fileMode & S_IROTH) {
    printf("You have General permissions:");
    if (fileMode & S_IREAD) { printf(" Read "); }
    if (fileMode & S_IWRITE) { printf("Write "); }
    if (fileMode & S_IEXEC) { printf("Execute"); }
    printf("\n\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `struct stat buf` occurs at file scope and as a local variable of `main`.

The problem is simple: you never call **stat**(2).  When you call `permission`, you're passing an uninitialized buffer.  Apparently, it's all zeros, and none of your `if` statements evaluates to true.

Each child process has its own address space.  Whether `buf` is defined locally or globally, it will appear in the child's address space, because it's a copy of its parent's.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code on how to pass it to permission();

Comment: I think up the wrong tree barking you are.  Your difficulty is not in failing to pass the information to your function.  Your difficulty is that `buf` has no data in it because you never populate it with `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Like James Lowden said, your `struct stat buf` is a local variable of main, and can't currently be used in your function `permission()`.

Then, you have to pass a "non-null" buffer, for example, initialized by 0's, and then the program will be able to enter your `if` statements

Let me know if this helped

Comment: I tried using (struct stat buf) as a local variable inside (permissions()) and it prints Owner permission: Read Write Execute everytime even for file i know dont have those permissions im kinda lost as to where to go from here any clues?